# why i have to run "FLUSH HOSTS;" every day in my project

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, devops, digital-ocean

I have a LEMP stack project that is hosted on digital ocean. that shows error

```
Host '167.71.227.200' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
```

every day i use `FLUSH HOSTS;` otherwise it give me same error.
what should i do to solve it permanently.
i'm not to digital host and ops in general.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely because you have frequent errors when clients try to connect to your MySQL Server. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/host-cache.html#blocked-host

> After `max_connect_errors` failed requests without a successful
> connection, the server assumes that something is wrong (for example,
> that someone is trying to break in), and blocks the host from further
> connection requests.
>
> To unblock blocked hosts, flush the host cache.

It's tempting to increase the value of `max_connect_errors`, but that will only delay the problem slightly. The fact that your server is seeing so many errors probably indicates a root cause that you need to address another way.

For example, this could be caused by an unstable network between the client and the MySQL Server, so connection attempts frequently fail. You should improve the network reliability, or else move the client to a host that has a more stable network.

This is likely not a code problem, but an infrastructure problem.

Comment: thank for answer , can you tell me where  do i find that out , like some kind of error log or something.

Comment: The MySQL errors are in the manual page I linked to. As for your network, I have no way of knowing anything about how your network is configured. I suggest you talk to your IT staff and networking engineers.

Comment: i don't have it staff that's the problem.

Comment: i found out my problem . i had created an slave database and deleted that afterword.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to close the database connection in your application.
Use conn.close() to ensure the connection is closed after each query